How to hide asp combobox according to selected asp combobox by javascript in asp.net
I have two asp combobox one with the name of cmb_stocktype while second with the name of cmb_tagno. Now, my question is that when I select cmb_stocktype with the value of WithStock then cmb_tagno should be show else it should be hide by javascript.
Here is my following code,
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" id="cmb_stocktype" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="WithStock">WITH STOCK</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="WithoutStock">WITHOUT STOCK</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>                                    

<asp:DropDownList ID="cmb_tagno" runat="server" Style="width:90%;" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:DropDownList>

$("#<%= cmb_stocktype.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    if ($("#<%= cmb_stocktype.ClientID %>").val() == "WithStock") {
        $("#<%=cmb_tagno.ClientID%>").show()
    }
    else {
        $("#<%=cmb_tagno.ClientID%>").hide()
    }
});

I used style.display and style.visibility still didn't work.

Use .on("change", function () ... instead of .change(function ()...

$("#<%= cmb_stocktype.ClientID %>").on("change", function () {
if ($("#<%= cmb_stocktype.ClientID %>").val() == "WithStock") {
$("#<%=cmb_tagno.ClientID%>").show()
}
else {
$("#<%=cmb_tagno.ClientID%>").hide()
}
});
@DA tried didn't work

Put a console log and check if it enters in change event, then try to see it find the IDs you want... try to use Static id Mode just to test.... do some debugging

@DA I tried with alert and in that value is coming perfectly but that combobox is not hide.

style.setProperty("display ", "none", "important"); Try like this... use important... maybe u have another style that is keeping it visible.... IDK

@DA document.getElementById('cmb_tagno').style.setProperty("display ", "none", "important");....I tried didn't work

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Are you getting a postback  when changing the value of cmb_stockType? You may need to pass the arguments and call e.preventDefault() to prevent the postback from blowing all of this up.

@ClearlyClueless no i didn't getting postback call can you elaborate with code?

You don't show how you are filling the 2nd dropdownlist, and without any values, it not going to show nor render in the page.
Also, it is as a better rule to define the event code in the given control's markup in place of writing some JavaScript to attach some event to some control, as then you have code to add some event to the markup (and where and how you going to know that when looking at the given control's markup? = answer you can't). And then of course having to write code to define what event code to run also introduces additional locations for your JavaScript and you the developer to maintain, look at, and find on the page!
And this approach of course introduces additional possible failure points in your code.
Assuming you have jQuery available, then this code should work:
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control"
            ID="cmb_stocktype" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            onchange="myhide()" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="WithStock">WITH STOCK</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="WithoutStock">WITHOUT STOCK</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="cmb_tagno" runat="server" 
            Style="width:90%;" 
            CssClass="form-control" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="Test1">Test1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <script>

            function myhide() {

                var cboValue = $('#cmb_stocktype').find('option:selected').val()
                var cboText = $('#cmb_stocktype').find('option:selected').text()
                // alert('Value = ' + cboValue + '  Text = ' + cboText)

                if (cboValue == 'WithStock') {
                    $('#cmb_tagno').show()
                }
                else {
                    $('#cmb_tagno').hide()
                }
            }

        </script>

I of course for ease of use added the ClientIdMode="Static" to the first dropdown list.


I applied your same code but still output is not coming. Don't know what's happening...!!!

Are you sure you have jQuery installed? when you launch the web page, hit f12 for the browser debug tools, and click on "console". Does the page show any errors?
